$\sigma$-homomorphism preserving $\sigma$-distributivity
I am basing some of my thesis on Introduction to Boolean Algebras by Givant and Halmos.
My current goal is to leverage the countable chain condition to define conditional probability measures.
In chapter 31 about measure algebras, Lemma 1 states the following

Let $\nu$ be a normalized measure on a Boolean $\sigma$-algebra $B$, and let $M$ be the $\sigma$-ideal of elements of measures zero. If $A=B\setminus A$ and if $f$ is the projection of $B$ onto $A$, then there exists a unique measure $\mu$ on $A$ such that $\mu(f(b))=\nu(b)$ for all $b\in B$; the measure $\mu$ is positive.

Moreover, $A$ satisfies the countable chain condition (ccc) and $f$ is a $\sigma$-homomorphism.
We say that $B$ is $\sigma$-distributive if
\begin{align*}
\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb N} \bigvee_{j\in \mathbb N} b_{i,j}=\bigvee_{j\in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}}\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb N} b_{i,j(i)}
\end{align*}
for any collection $\{ b_{i,j} \}_{i\in\mathbb N,j\in\mathbb N}$ in $B$.
I think that the construction preserves $\sigma$-distributivity, i.e.,

If $B$ is $\sigma$-distributive, then $A$ is $\sigma$-distributive.

Let $\{ a_{i,j} \}_{i\in\mathbb N,j\in\mathbb N}$ in $A$ and let $\{ b_{i,j} \}_{i\in\mathbb N,j\in\mathbb N}$ in $B$ be such that $a_{i,j}=f(b_{i,j})$.
For any $k\in\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, then we have $\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb N} a_{i,k(i)}\leq\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb N}\bigvee_{j\in\mathbb N} a_{i,j}$ and so
\begin{align*}
\bigvee_{j\in\mathbb N^\mathbb N}\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb N} a_{i,j(i)}\leq\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb N}\bigvee_{j\in\mathbb N} a_{i,j}
\end{align*}
Therefore we only need to prove the converse inequality, which I didn't manage to do. I would really appreciate any help.

If the sets on level $i$ all have measure at most $2^{-i}$ then $\bigwedge_i a_{i,j(i)}=0$, always. If at the same time each level is a partition of the Boolean algebra, $\bigvee_j a_{i,j}=1$, then your inequality becomes $0\le1$. Both happen in the measure algebra of the unit interval.

@KPHart Thanks a lot! Would you also have an insight about if for all $i$m only two of the $a_{i,j}$ are non-zero, in otherwords about $$\bigwedge_{i\in\mathbb N} (a_i \lor b_i) = \bigvee_{U\subseteq \mathbb N} \left[ \bigwedge_{i\in U} a_i \land\bigwedge_{i\notin U} b_i \right]$$.
Similarly, we can prove $\geq$ and we cannot have the same argument about levels as the one you mentionned.

Yes: look at the product measure on ${0,1}^\mathbb{N}$, with $a_{i,0}={x:x_i=0}$ and $a_{i,1}={x:x_i=1}$. Both have measure $\frac12$. For every function $j$ you have $\bigwedge_ia_{i,j(i)}=0$.

To give a more complete answer: consider the unit interval with Lebesgue measure.
For each $i$ let $b_{i,0}$ be the union of the intervals $[2k\cdot2^{-i},(2k+1)\cdot2^{-i})$ for $0\le k<2^{i-1}$, and $b_{i,1}$ its complement.
For the corresponding equivalence classes $a_{i,j}$ we have $\bigwedge_i(a_{i,0}\vee a_{i,1})=1$ and $\bigwedge_ia_{i,j(i)}=0$ for all functions $j$. (This corresponds to the product-measure example in my second comment and makes my first comment explicit.)
There is a connection with forcing: $\sigma$-distributive algebras do not add new countable objects to the universe. You can read about this in many books on Set Theory, e.g., Jech's Set Theory.
Also, there is a long article by David Fremlin about Measure Algebras in the Handbook of Boolean Algebras; it is very informative.
